# "Pull the shirt over his head"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Did he put it on or did he take it off? All Quiet On The Western Front

> He **pulls the shirt over his head** and buttons up his tunic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On.

This is not because the "pulls" phrasing is unambiguous, but because he buttons the tunic over it.  This shows he is getting dressed.

If he unbuttoned his tunic and then pulls the shirt over his head, he's getting undressed.